# What's the purpose of "type": "dark" in VSCode themes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VSCode themes, there is a json file that describes the theme's colors. There is a property named "type", which is describing whether or not the theme is a light or dark theme. However, does this also mean that VSCode defaults to the default dark theme's ([This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/dark_modern.json) one for dark themes if I'm not wrong) colors when it can't find a color it wants from the theme?

Comment: do you specify ALL possible theme colors, and all future theme colors as soon as VSC updates

Answer (score 0):

No, this type field only tells VS Code whether the theme is considered a dark, light or high contrast theme. It's impossible to determine that from the colors alone. With that information VS Code can list the theme in the correct section of the theme selector.

VS Code comes with a number of themes already, and one of them is selected as default (not sure if this just hard coded or dependent on the system it runs on), but that has nothing to do with other themes' type field.